# Что за странный инкремент ++x

Tags: java

Учу Java и столкнулся с каким-то новым для меня инкрементом.
Мне знаком x++.
А тут я столкнулся с ++x. Объясните пожалуйста что это за инкремент и как он работает

Comment: По каким материалам вы учите язык, что там постинкремент рассматривают, а преинкремент нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x++ даёт значение x, затем увеличивает его. Например

```
x = 1
1 + x++
```

даст результат 2, и x тоже станет 2

++x наоборот - сначала увеличивает x, а потом использует его значение

Такое же выражение в этом случае даст 3, т.к. x ещё до сложения с 1 уже будет равен 2